# How to change an array of objects containing ids and children references into a nested tree structured object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create an object with a tree structure from data that looks as follow:

```
nodes: [
  { name: "Ben", id: 1 next: [2, 3], depth: 0 },
  { name: "Mike", id: 2, next: [4, 5], depth: 1 },
  { name: "Jen", id: 3, next: [6], depth: 1 },
  { name: "Sue", id: 4, next [], depth: 2 },
  { name: "Jeff", id: 5, next: [], depth: 2 },
  { name: "Bob", id: 6, next: [], depth: 3 }
]
```

The tree like object would look like this:

```
root: 
  { name: "Ben", children: 
    [
      { name: "Mike", children: 
        [
          { name: "Sue" },
          { name: "Jeff" }
        ]
      },
      { name: "Jen", children: 
        [
          { name: "Bob" }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  }
```

I can assign the root and go through the objects in the next array like this:

```
const root = { name: nodes[0].name };
   root.children = [];
   nodes[0].next.map(function (next) {
       nodes.map((node, i) => {
           if (next === node.id) {
               root.children.push({name: nodes[i].name})
           }
       })
   });
```

I'm not sure how to find next for the nodes pushed to the children array. The number of objects in the nodes array may vary, so the depth of children arrays may vary too. How can you create a new children array based on this variable and push the right properties to it?

Comment: is the nodes array sorted by id?

Comment: Are you guaranteed only one root, ie one node with `depth: 0`?

Comment: Seems like you'd be able to do this fairly easily in two passes; the first to create a map of `id` to node and the second to construct the tree

Comment: yes, there's only one root. It'll have `depth:0`. There might be other nodes, not connected to any other that have a depth of 0 too. The root's index will always be 0 though.

Comment: The array is not sorted by id @HimanshuTanwar

Comment: So what should the end result look like with multiple `depth:0` nodes? Should `root` be an array instead?

Comment: The nodes that have `depth:0` besides the root won't be inside `nodes.next`

Comment: @Vincent yes, I understand that, but your desired result `root` is a single object. What happens to the other `depth:0` nodes?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a good edgecase. I didn't ran into that when trying this. I would like to keep them out of the root object

Comment: Also, is it important that nodes with no `next` entries do not have a `children` property? For consistency, I'd always have one present, even if it's an empty array

Comment: I would like to use it for a D3 Collapsible Indented Tree, I am not sure if it would couse a problem when you pass D3 the root object

Comment: Might just create a root object that contains all the roots as children?

Comment: That would be ok too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pass, map the nodes by `id` into something resembling the desired output. This has the added benefit of not mutating the original `nodes` objects

```
const idMap = nodes.reduce((map, { id, name }) => map.set(id, { name }), new Map())
```

Then iterate the nodes, reducing that to an array of roots

```
const roots = nodes.reduce((arr, node) => {
  let obj = idMap.get(node.id)
  if (node.next && node.next.length) {
    obj.children = node.next.map(id => idMap.get(id))
  }
  if (node.depth === 0) {
    arr.push(obj)
  }
  return arr
}, [])
```

Then find the first one with children

```
const root = roots.find(rootNode => rootNode.children)
```

```js
const nodes = [{"name":"Ben","id":1,"next":[2,3],"depth":0},{"name":"Mike","id":2,"next":[4,5],"depth":1},{"name":"Jen","id":3,"next":[6],"depth":1},{"name":"Sue","id":4,"next":[],"depth":2},{"name":"Jeff","id":5,"next":[],"depth":2},{"name":"Bob","id":6,"next":[],"depth":3}]

const idMap = nodes.reduce((map, { id, name }) => map.set(id, { name }), new Map())

const roots = nodes.reduce((arr, node) => {
  let obj = idMap.get(node.id)
  if (node.next && node.next.length) {
    obj.children = node.next.map(id => idMap.get(id))
  }
  if (node.depth === 0) {
    arr.push(obj)
  }
  return arr
}, [])

const root = roots.find(rootNode => rootNode.children)

console.info(root)
```

Comment: Had some fixes to make but now it's all good (with a runnable example)

Comment: This works perfectly, very nice. For some reason I had to delete `length` from `(node.next.length)` but it still works perfectly. Sometimes when I make something work it feels like things are going in the right way. And sometimes, like now, it feels like there still so much to learn. I wouldn't have thought of this myself, Thank you so much!

Comment: @Vincent you must have nodes without a `next` property. You can change it to `node.next && node.next.length`

Comment: @Vincent I've come up with what I think is an even simpler version that iterates the `nodes` array twice instead of the `idMap` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive function and go until next array length is 0 !!

```js
var nodes =  [
  { name: "Ben", id: 1, next: [2,3], depth: 0},
  { name: "Mike", id: 2, next: [4,5], depth: 1},
  { name: "Jen", id: 3, next: [6], depth: 1},
  { name: "Sue", id: 4, next: [], depth: 2},
  { name: "Jeff", id: 5, next: [], depth: 2 },
  { name: "Bob", id: 6, next: [], depth: 3 }
];

var root = {};

nodes.forEach(v => {
  if(v.depth == 0) { // check root 0
     root.name = v.name
     if(v.next.length > 0 ) { // check next array has more than 0
        root.children = []
        findChild(root,v);
     }
  }
});

function findChild(root,c) {
  c.next.forEach(v => {
     var child =  nodes.find(x => x.id === v)
     var next = {name: child.name};
      if(child.next.length > 0) {
          next.children = [];
          findChild(next,child);
      }
       root.children.push(next); // push to real root
  })
}

console.log(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use an id lookup table:

```
const hash = {};

for(const node of nodes) 
   hash[node.id] = node;

for(const node of nodes) node.children = node.next.map(id => ((hash[id].parent = node), hash[id]));

const roots = nodes.filter(n => !n.parent);
```

As there could be multiple roots, this gives an array of roots.

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed id `1` is the root

Comment: doesn't this return an array of objects like the one in my first codeblock of this question? When I try it, the children aren't nested inside the parent's children array

Comment: @vincent they are nested?

Comment: When I try it, it doesn't return a children array for Ben, for example.